# Parse JWT and get Microsoft AAD from sub with Python

Tags: python, jwt, microsoft-teams

I am writing a incoming webhook for MS Teams and when I have a button that is a `Action.HttpPost`. When the user clicks a button the payload is sent back to my server. In the header is a JWT token. I need to parse it with python then get the `'sub'` and query the Microsoft graph to determine which user clicked the button. Is this possible with a incoming webhook?

Comment: Please have a look at this nodejs sample - [graph-activity-feed](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/graph-activity-feed/nodejs) Here have a look at Readme to understand how to create app registration and you need to provide permissions required to call [get User API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). The code to get the token is inside auth.js and you can follow this sample to call Graph API.

Comment: You can also follow the same in by following this doc to [get token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: I guess it's resolved. Perhaps my understanding of Azure just needs to be better. Slack makes this process much easier, but I just need to dive in and understand it better. thanks.